# Core Data Entities can't see while adding NSManageObject Subclass in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I created project with core data, and I also create many entities and their relationships with each other. What happened it was deleted by mistake but I also keeping backup of project. I fetched core data file and import this to latest one and imported successfully. Now I want to create NSManageObject subclass and I can't found any entity over there but I can see core data file name. So kindly help me on this how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake, I didn't check mark my Core data Data model file which has entities like show in following screen shot. I need more rest :) 
[image: Screen shot]
Cheers